# Shortcut for formula = IF(A > 0; A; B)

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there anyway to shortcut formula `=IF(A > 0; A; B)`?

There two problems with this formula:

1) Excel will calculate `A` twice which could reduce general perfomance if `A` has some complex formula behind it.

2) `A` could be a long formula and using it twice in IF statement makes it less readable.

Comment: The simple answer is to use a work cell `C`, which is set to the formula `A`. Then the conditional becomes `=IF(C>B,C,B)`.

Comment: That's what my first thought was but sometimes you will need an entire worksheet dedicated to calculating `A` values.

Comment: @FamousSnake, One possible Short Cut is `NAMED Range` in case of Longer Formula to test as A1  like this,, `=IF(NEWANS>0,NEWANS,B1)` , I've use `SUMPRODUCT` based on Cell value and assigned Name `NEWANS` to the Formula cell, otherwise Formula has to follow the set procedure to test values !!

Comment: @FamousSnake - The only other answer may be to use scripting to calculate the value efficiently, but I normally use LibreOffice, so I cannot say how this would be done in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes............but only in the special case of ignoring the possibility of **negative values**.  Consider something like:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/A1),B1)
```

It will return A1 unless A1=0, then it will return B1.

*(ignore this approach if the item being tested can be negative.)*

Comment: While this will technically work, it doesn't make things easily understandable for anyone looking at it in the future and trying to work out what it does.

Comment: I don't see the issue for negative numbers. I think the result will be correct for them too. ( 1/-5 = - 0.2 & 1/-0.2 = - 5)

Comment: @squaregoldfish  **I agree with you 100% !**

Comment: @MátéJuhász  The formula will work, but it will treat negative like positive and not return B1

Comment: It's a solution for `=IF(A <> 0; A; B)`. Do you have any ideas how we can use it for other conditions?